# Playwright: Can I run a subset of tests based on a tag?

Tags: annotations, tags, playwright

I'm used to using Cucumber where I can tag my feature files with annotations like @prodSafe and run only tests with that tag on my production environment.

Is there a way I can do that with Playwright? I want to run all my tests on dev but then on production, there are tests I'd like to skip for things like deleting users, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To tag a test in playwright, we just add the tag, for example `@smokeDev` to the test definition:

```js
test('@smokeDev - Login to dev with valid credentials', async ({ page }) 
      ...  
});
```

To run all tests having a tag you can use

```bash
npx playwright test --grep '@smokeDev'
```

This command will run all tests having `@smokeDev` tag.
It is also possible to pick multiple tags by simply combining them with `|`

For instance:

```bash
npx playwright test --grep '@smokeDev|smokeProd'
```

This command will run all tests having either the tag

- `@smokeDev` or
- `@smokeProd`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to *AND* tests, use this format:

```
npx playwright  -g "(?=.*@Smoke)(?=.*@beta)"
```

This will run tests annotated with `@Smoke` AND `@beta`

#### OR

To run tests based on tags with OR combinations:

```
npx playwright test -g "@Smoke|@beta"
```

This will run tests annotated with `@Smoke` *OR* `@beta`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about the grep feature documented under "Annotations" in the docs:

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-annotations#tag-tests

There are more elaborate options on that same page which you could use instead, such as `test.skip`.